# Keras Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, keras

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network on Keras 1.2.2 on top of Theano 0.8.2 (python 2.7). I am able to import keras and theano without getting an error.

The error only occurs after circa 2-5 minutes after running the following code.

```
#Prepare images etc.

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                        border_mode='valid',
                        input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters * 2, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Which creates following output:

```
X_train shape: (984, 1, 1000, 1000)
984 train samples
246 test samples
Train on 984 samples, validate on 246 samples
Epoch 1/4
[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

So it seems like the model was compiled and training has started. I was able to train a model before with smaller images (shape: (400, 1, 500, 500). Could changing the number of training images and their size lead to the error? I also tried updating Keras to 2.0 and Theano to the current dev version but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `train_on_batch()` and let me know whether you can finish training a single batch. Second, reduce the batch size (to 1 if necessary) and see if the segmentation fault goes away (unlikely though).

Comment: Can you update your keras and try again? https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html  with pip install keras --upgrade. Can you check your memory usage? Is it going beyond your total available memory? Try running gdb python yourprogram.py and then write `backtrace.`

Comment: Like I said, I updated Keras and Theano before and it didn't help. unfortunately I can't install/run gpd because I'm not root, and getting our admin to install things takes forever. :D

Comment: Also, when I check memory consumption through the top command, the process takes around 20%, so it should no be a memory issue.

Comment: I changed the size of the images from 1000x1000 to 500x500. It now started training on the first batch. Although I run it on a machine with 200GB RAM, currently it seems like it is a memory issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it comes from large images in input (in my case (200x2200). And it is not a 'direct memory' issue because the data is loaded in the RAM. Also, by changing the number of OMP_NUM_THREADS I can generate or not the segfault... @christian_bock do you have any update on this issue?

Comment: Yeah, it seemed like the image size was the problem for me, too. When I reduced it I was able to get rid of the error. Didn't dig any deeper though.

Answer (score -1):

If you run K.clearsession() incorrectly, you may get a segmentation fault.  This is because each neural network graph is held in a default session, when you clear the session, the graph gets removed from memory.  Putting K.clearsession() is smart to do at the top of a code (esp if you're using jupyter) because it will clear any graphs held in memory.

If you have this in  your code, try removing it! Good Luck!

Comment: Try adding an explanation on why `K.clearsession()` would cause a segmentation fault to help future readers understand the root of the problem.